# "Asked me to" without a verb at the end of sentence

Tags: grammar, prepositions, verbs

Let's say that someone tells me:

> I am asking you to not chew gum.

I could reply to that statement:

> I will not chew gum as you have asked me to.

Does the previous statement make sense, or do I need to reword it to:

> I will not chew gum as you have asked me to do

I have googled "asked me to" and I found out that a song has a title with those words: [If You Asked Me To](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_You_Asked_Me_To). The fact that a song was written by a American author gives me some assurance that both sentences are correct. However, I would appreciate an expert voice on this issue.

Comment: Firstly I would make the request "I am asking you **not to** chew gum." Secondly if asked, I would reply "I will not chew gum, as you asked", to simplify a clumsy sentence.

Comment: Thank you @WeatherVane! I have edited my question to reflect your first observation. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Please don't change the question in response to comments, unless it provides more clarity. You'll end up with a question which no-one will know why you asked, without delving into the edit history. Rolled back.

Comment: @WeatherVane Actually both "to not" or "not to" can be used, the difference being in emphasis.

Comment: Just  pointing this out: there are times where you do not need to repeat the verb: Did you ask me not to chew gum? Yes, I asked you not to.

Answer (score 1):

When responding to negative requests, use the negative:

> (Could I ask you not to practice your drums at three in the morning?)
>
> OK. Since you **asked me not to,** I will stop practicing my drums at three in the morning.

It doesn't matter whether the request was phrased, "not to practice", or, "to not practice" -- as user3169 mentions, there may be a difference in emphasis, but most of the time it's not a significant difference.

Also, as Lambie points out, it's not common to repeat the entire request when responding.  It's more natural to reply:

> OK, I won't.

or possibly:

> OK, since you asked, I won't.

Side note: Be aware that song lyrics are not always grammatical.  Songs are musical *poetry*, and poetry is often unconstrained by grammatical rules, possibly in *any* language.  That being said, "asked me to" is both grammatical and idiomatic.